# Accessing column from SQL JOIN in WebGrid

Tags: c#, razor, html-helper

I will show some data in my WebGrid. The SQL Statement looks like this:

```
mSQL = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id";
```

In table1 and table2 I have some columns with same name. If I want to Access a "duplicated" column from one specified table, I was used to (with Ado) Access it with:

```
[tablename].[columnname]
```

But this seems not to work in the WebGrid:

```
var mLocations = mDB.Query(mSQL);
var mGrid = new WebGrid(source: mLocations, rowsPerPage: 50, canPage: true);
mGridHTML = mGrid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid wide",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: mGrid.Columns(
        mGrid.Column(header: "V_1", format:@item.table1.viewedcount),
        mGrid.Column(header: "V_2", format:@item.table2.viewedcount)
    )
);
```

How can I Access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement would not return the results into 2 separate queries.

Consider the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM [TableA] A
INNER JOIN [TAbleA] A2
ON A.ID = A2.ID
```

Now try and select a column from this query

```
SELECT Example.ID
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [TableA] A
    INNER JOIN [TAbleA] A2
    ON A.ID = A2.ID
) Example
```

Its impossible to determine which ID to extract.

So you would have to do something like the following

```
SELECT Example.ID, Example.ID2
FROM
(
    SELECT A.ID AS ID, A2.ID AS ID2
    FROM [TableA] A
    INNER JOIN [TableA] A2
    ON A.ID = A2.ID
) Example
```

SO to fix your issue...

```
mSQL = "SELECT table1.viewedcount AS table1ViewCount, table2.viewedcount AS table2ViewCount FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id";
```

...As your query and then setup your grid like so...

```
var mLocations = mDB.Query(mSQL);
var mGrid = new WebGrid(source: mLocations, rowsPerPage: 50, canPage: true);
mGridHTML = mGrid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid wide",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: mGrid.Columns(
        mGrid.Column(header: "V_1", format:@item.table1ViewCount),
        mGrid.Column(header: "V_2", format:@item.table2ViewCount)
    )
);
```

Comment: You´re not right. `SELECT tbl_A.*, tbl_B.* FROM tbl_A INNER JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_A.id = tbl_B.id` works fine - on MSSQL. Accessing on of the `id` columns works with `tbl_A.id` od `tbl_B.id`. Try it out. Building a subquery is not my solution.

Comment: Yes the query works fine, but that is not the query you are performing (`SELECT tbl_A.*, tbl_B.*`). My point about the subquery is that you cannot specify to select a duplicate column name. you must alias that column name.

Comment: Updated my answer to fix your issue.